# Size of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, sys

I am trying to get the actual size of a dict in the memory. I got a weird results and I am looking forward to your feedback.

```py
a = {}
for i in range(2):
    a[i] = {}
    for j in range(1000):
        a[i][j] = j

sys.getsizeof(a), sys.getsizeof(a[0]), sys.getsizeof(a[1])
```

the results is 272, 49424, 49424 bytes. I expect the size of a is the sum of a[0] and a[1].

but if tried the following

```py
a = {}
for i in range(2000):
   a[i] = [i,i,i]
sys.getsizeof(a)
```

size of a = 196880 bytes. The first one has 2000 keys and the second one has 2 keys and each one has dict with 1000 keys.

Comment: The size of the dictionary is only the size that the dict itself occupies - it does not account for objects that the dict may be referring to: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof

Comment: So your comment that "I expect the size of a is the sum of a[0] and a[1]. " is not true since the dict actually holds the references to the dicts you create & not the dicts themselves

Comment: `a` doesn't contain a pair of lists. It contains a pair of *references* to lists, which (strictly speaking) is why `sys.getsizeof(a)` does not include the sizes of those lists. (Likewise, `sys.getsizeof[0]` is only returning the memory used for list itself, not the memory use by each `int` object *referenced* by the list.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments,  What if I need to calculate the size of the dict and the object it refers to ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to determine the size of the dict, and the sizes of all its keys and values, recursively (I wish Python had a built-in function to do this).  I have used variations of [this receipe](https://goshippo.com/blog/measure-real-size-any-python-object/) a number of times:

```
import sys

def get_size(obj, seen=None):
    """Recursively finds size of objects"""
    size = sys.getsizeof(obj)
    if seen is None:
        seen = set()
    obj_id = id(obj)
    if obj_id in seen:
        return 0
    # Important mark as seen *before* entering recursion to gracefully handle
    # self-referential objects
    seen.add(obj_id)
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        size += sum([get_size(v, seen) for v in obj.values()])
        size += sum([get_size(k, seen) for k in obj.keys()])
    elif hasattr(obj, '__dict__'):
        size += get_size(obj.__dict__, seen)
    elif hasattr(obj, '__iter__') and not isinstance(obj, (str, bytes, bytearray)):
        size += sum([get_size(i, seen) for i in obj])
    return size
```

I have occasionally had to make versions of this that work for other custom types, Numpy arrays, and the like.  Sadly there's no perfect generic solution.